# Workaround for firewall that is blocking unsolicited traffic

Tags: linux, networking, ip, firewall, iptables

I have AT&T wireless at my house for home internet. Where I am located it
is rural and don't have many option's for ISP's. My goal is to be able to SSH back to my house and possibly view my security system. Can someone help me figure out the best way to approach the firewall that blocks all unsolicited connections to ports. I believe apps have the ability to get around this by connecting out, instead of listening on the port for incoming connections. I do code and could create something if someone could help point me in right direction of what to research.

I was looking into reverse ssh port forwarding, would that help with my issue?

router model: WG3526
DMZ open to private IP.

NMAP ran on internal IP

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-17 13:48 EDT Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.157 Host is up (0.000051s latency). Not shown: 996 closed ports PORT    STATE SERVICE 
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp open  http 
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

NMAP ran on external IP Host is up (0.038s latency). rDNS record for
166.216.165.110: mobile-166-216-165-110.mycingular.net Not shown: 996 closed ports PORT    STATE SERVICE
 25/tcp  open  smtp
 80/tcp  open  http 
 443/tcp open  https
 705/tcp open  agentx
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what "the firewall issue" is? Not everyone is familiar with AT&T wireless.

Comment: At&T appears to block all unsolicited traffic. So even on my openWRT router/hotspot it doesn't matter if I open a DMZ or port forwarding. Only certain ports which include port 80/25/443.

Comment: What's the make and model of the ISP router? What are you trying exactly that is not working that indicates the ISP is blocking something from reaching your ISP router? If you're in the US, then I doubt anything is being blocked getting to the ISP router for SSH port 22 but explain what you tried and the syntax or whatever you are using, and what error message you are getting, timeout, etc.? What's configured where, how are you connecting to this with what tools, etc. and what have you configured in the router accordingly to open such ports. Is this DSL or what type of Internet connection?

Comment: Please elaborate on your Internet setup. You mention AT&T wireless (whatever that means) and a OpenWrt router. How is this all set up? Are you sure you even have a public IP address and are not behind carrier-grade NAT?

Comment: I did some research after trying to get it working for a couple days, and everything pointed at AT&T Wireless blocking non solicited connections for hotspots. I would open DMZ up to specific IP and would still get connection refused. When i would scan my webserver/ssh server internally I could tell the ports where open, but from outside I was never able to see them open. My understanding is that AT&T does this to prevent people from doing what I am attempting to do and want's you to have a business account to have a public IP.

Comment: I bet you are right, I am behind some carrier grade nat, thought I could just use the public facing IP that I would retrieve from checking via website along with dynamic DNS client running on my server.

when I say At&T wireless, I am simply talking about being on a LTE connection and glorified hotspot.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select ‘‘I need to merge user profiles’’ to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://superuser.com/users/1022971/jonathan-philpot and https://superuser.com/users/1023141/user2190928.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I have found that the best approach is remote port forwarding. AT&T appears to have some NAT setup outside my control and blocks the traffic before my hotspot/router.

I am currently using serveo and sshreach.me which opens a remote tunnel.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting and editing your own posts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://superuser.com/users/1022971/jonathan-philpot and https://superuser.com/users/1023141/user2190928.